# Prevent OOM while displaying full page Images

Tags: android

I recently implemented a tutorial for my app. This tutorial is done through a viewpager with full page images. There are 10 images that are approx  170kb. I have had no issues with memory while testing but I see error reports coming in with OOM exceptions. I use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and recycle each bitmap manually when the fragment is destroyed.

```
  private class TutorialPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int[] tutorialImages;

    public TutorialPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int [] tutorialImages) {
        super(fm);
        this.tutorialImages = tutorialImages;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(C.BUNDLE_TUTORIAL_IMAGE, tutorialImages[i]);
        b.putBoolean(TutorialPageFragment.FINAL_TUTORIAL_SCREEN, i == getCount()-1 && !singleTutorial);
        TutorialPageFragment frag = new TutorialPageFragment();
        frag.attachListener(TutorialFragment.this);
        frag.setArguments(b);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tutorialImages.length;
    }
}
```

Then the fragments that are in the view pager

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial_page, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, v);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getArguments().getInt(C.BUNDLE_TUTORIAL_IMAGE));
    tutorialImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    if (getArguments().getBoolean(FINAL_TUTORIAL_SCREEN, false)) {
        finishTutorial.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (prefs.getBoolean(C.PREF_TUTORIAL_SHOW, false)) {
        _setupSwipeClose();
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Drawable drawable = tutorialImage.getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap().recycle();
    }
}
```

Any tips on how else I could prevent OOM exceptions?

Comment: Are you settings the offscreenPageLimit or anything like that? If you put a log in your onDestroyView, are you seeing it get called as you scroll through your pager as you would expect?

Comment: Yup only 3 fragments are active at a time. The other ones get destroyed correctly